# Grails (StaleObjectStateException) - set domain object's property dependent on its ID after saving

Tags: grails, properties, controller, grails-domain-class

Assuming that I have the following domain class:

```
@Entity
class TestDomain {

    public static final ID_PREFIX = "prefix-"

    String uniqueId

    constriaints = {
        uniqueId nullable: true
    }
}
```

By grails default the domain class does also have an `id` property. Following this, I want to set the `uniqueId` in that way that when I create a new `TestDomain` object the `uniqueId` property contains something like `prefix-1` for the first created object, `prefix-2` for the second, and so on.

My approach was to realize that within `save` action of the `TestDomainController`:

```
def save(TestDomain testDomainInstance) {
    if (testDomainInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (testDomainInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond testDomainInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    testDomainService.save(testDomainInstance) //.save flush:true
    testDomainInstance.uniqueId = TestDomain.ID_PREFIX + testDomainInstance.id
    testDomainService.save(testDomainInstance) //.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'TestDomain.label', default: 'Test Domain'), testDomainInstance.id])
            redirect testDomainInstance
        }
        '*' { respond testDomainInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
```

However, once I save the object I get the following error:

```
StaleObjectStateException occurred when processing request: ...
Message
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [test.TestDomain#1]
```

Now, what could I do to get this running? Or, is there a possibility to set the value of `uniqueId` in a more beautiful way? Currently, I'm a little bit stuck.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT:

I now tried to `redirect` to another action after the first `save` in order to set the `uniqueId` there. However, I get the same error. Even if I use `save(flush: true)` within the `testDomainService` the matter doesn't change at all.

Another approach was to put all the first save, the alteration and the second save into the `testDomainService`'s `save` method but without success - the same error occured. The service is transactional.

Is it generally not possible to save a domain object, alter it and save it again within the same transaction?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
class TestDomain {
    public static final ID_PREFIX = "prefix-"
    String uniqueId
     constriaints = {
        uniqueId nullable: true
    }
  def afterInsert() {
     uniqueId = ID_PREFIX + id
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but I get the same error (StaleObjectStateException) ... did it work in your application?

Comment: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException comes if same object is being modified by two thread at same time.Please read this.http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/What-is-Optimistic-and-Pessimistic-Locking%3F